# D-ITG traffic sending

Tags: python

I am generating the D-ITG traffic using the following command on the terminal,
command :

`ITGSend -a 10.1.1.129 -T TCP -sp 49000 -rp 49000 -C 100 -c 500 -t 2000 -l sender.log`

Then it shows the following error message :

```
flowSender: Address family not supported by protocol
Could not bind a new socket. Flow ID: 1
Error - FlowSender interrupted by an error
Finished sending packets of flow ID: 1
```

So please suggest me for the better solution to set the source port in D-ITG traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you should refer this link : **http://traffic.comics.unina.it/software/ITG/manual/**
For setting the source and destination port in DITG, Following options are available .

```
-sp <src_port>          Set the source port (default: Set by O.S.).
This option applies only to traffic flow.

-rp <dest_port>         Set the destination port (default: 8999).
This option applies only to traffic flows.
```

According to the example they enlisted in the DITG manual we can use these options for setting the source and destination port.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still using older versions of D-ITG for any reason (lower than 2.8.1), the solution would be disabling IPv6 on both ends:

```
sudo -S sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo -S sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo -S sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

D-ITG **2.8.1** (r66M) does not have this issue.

UPDATE:
Version 2.8.1 does have issues running the following scenario (works fine on 2.8.0):

```
ITGRecv -Sp 9001
ITGSend -D -a 2001:db8:1234:100::2 -sa fd00:10::11 -Sdp 9001 -rp 23150 -sp 23150 -T TCP -t 30000 -C 128.0 -c 400
```

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) suggests the range 49152 to 65535 (215+214 to 216−1) for dynamic or private ports. Many Linux kernels use the port range 32768 to 60999.

On my linux Debian

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

If you use values between in this range it will works.

Sender side:

```
# ITGSend -a 172.16.25.129  -rp 32769 -C 100 -c 500 -t 20000 -x recv_log_file
ITGSend version 2.8.1 (r1023)
Compile-time options: sctp dccp bursty multiport
Started sending packets of flow ID: 1
Finished sending packets of flow ID: 1
```

Receiver side:

```
# ITGRecv
ITGRecv version 2.8.1 (r1023)
Compile-time options: sctp dccp bursty multiport
Press Ctrl-C to terminate
Listening on UDP port : 32769
Finish on UDP port : 32769
Listening on UDP port : 32769
Finish on UDP port : 32769
```